# Converting a monetary value like 1.223.01 to decimal

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a monetary value like `1.223.01` but it is stored as a `varchar` so it is really like `'1.223.01'`.

I need this to be converted to `decimal` so I can do some calculations on it.

What I have tried is

```
SELECT Convert(decimal(18,2), '1.223.01') AS test
```

But I get a conversion error.

How can I convert this?

Comment: The problem is the format. In sql you have no 1000-point. Delete the point and it works. :)

Comment: is that: `1223.01` or `122301.00`?

Comment: Sorry I should of clarified, I need this much detail

Comment: You are storing as a decimal, the formatting won't matter. Just replace the periods with empty string before calling `convert`

Comment: I think I see where I went wrong here.

Comment: How did you resolve the problem?

Comment: Two Dot(.) are not allowed in a decimal number where It is not a matter for varchar. Change the value with one decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified what the output should be, so it's either `1223.01` or `122301.00` that you require.

So using some basic string manipulation you can get both of those values:

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(20) = '1.223.01'

-- remove all decimal points
SET @val = REPLACE(@val, '.', '')

-- convert value without decimals to get 122301.00
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2), @val) AS TestValue

-- add a decimal point before the last 2 digits to get 1223.01
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(18,2), LEFT(@val,LEN(@val) - 2) + '.' + 
                              RIGHT(@val, 2)) AS TestValue
```

This assumes that the values stored always have a decimal point with 2 digits after it.

Both can be done in a single `SELECT` if required, by substituting `REPLACE(@val, '.', '')` into the position of `@val` in the 2 queries.

```
DECLARE @val AS VARCHAR(20) = '1.223.01'

SELECT  CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), REPLACE(@val, '.', '')) AS TestValue

SELECT  CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), LEFT(REPLACE(@val, '.', ''),
                                LEN(REPLACE(@val, '.', '')) - 2) + '.'
                                + RIGHT(REPLACE(@val, '.', ''), 2)) AS TestValue
```

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of that format. Sounds like you have a varchar and not a money type. Here is how you can manipulate it.

First removing all periods. Then dividing by 1 to explain to sql-server that this is a numeric. Then multiply by .01 to change it into a decimal number

```
SELECT 
  replace(value, '.', '')/1*.01
FROM (values('1.223.01'),('1.111.223.75'),('0.01')) x(value)
```

Result:

```
1223.01
1111223.75
0.01
```